# What will be the regex expression?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to find the index of the first occurrence of any character except a tab(\t) in a string. I wrote the following code for this purpose -

```
line = "    BD/SW_Pro_test";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\t]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);


System.out.println("MATCHES AT ... "+ matcher.group(1));
```

Shouldn't I expect that the output will be - 1?
What is the problem in this code?

Thanks!

Comment: That and you need to call `matches` before any operation on the matcher.

Comment: Tried doing double escape \\t... no luck :(

Comment: @Tunaki, did you mean this - Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\t]");
  pattern.matches("[^\\t]", line);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

  if(matcher.groupCount()>0)
          System.out.println("MATCHES AT ... "+ matcher.group(1));
  else
          System.out.println("No match");

Comment: @ndn Nope, both `\t` and `\\t` are acceptable by regex engine in Java.

Comment: @Srijani What do you think `groupCount()` returns?

Comment: I think it return, number of matches

Comment: @Srijani And which part of documentation of that method makes you think that?

Comment: @Pshemo , may be I have interpreted it wrong. I read this line in documentation - groupCount
public int groupCount()
Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.

Comment: "number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern" means that it returns number of capturing groups which regex is build from. For instance if you have regex like `(foo)bar(baz)` this method will always return `2` because it it describes number of groups in pattern, not number of groups found in text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88296/discussion-between-srijani-and-pshemo).

Comment: I will try to post answer to your question here in few minutes. If you will have more questions feel free to leave comment under that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are misunderstanding what [`groupCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount--) method returns (don't feel bad about it, it is common misunderstanding for Java regex beginners).

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern

In other words it returns number of capturing groups used in pattern, not number of groups found in text.

For example, if we have regex like `(a)b(c+)` capturing groups are

- group 1 `(a)`
- group 2 `(c+)`

so `groupCount` for this pattern will return `2`.

What you seem to be searching for is something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("yourRegex");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourData);
while(m.find()){//this will iterate over your data and in each iteration handle single match
    //if you want to know about indexes of current match you can use m.start or m.start(groupID)
    String textFound = m.group();
    int position = m.start();
    //now you can handle data you found, 
    //like place them in some map which will remember match and its first position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me.

```
while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.start());
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, it will not compile because of `]` in first line.

Comment: Also if you want to break loop immediately you should consider using `if(condition){doSomething();}` rather than `while(condition){doSomething(); break}`. BTW I am not down-voter, but I can't also upvote your answer since it contains mistake.